InfluxDB: Is multiplexing good for storing variable number of parameters
Setup
Imagine there are a bunch of IoT devices, each of which is continuously monitored, e.g. once every few minutes. Thus, at every timestamp, each device produces a several floating-point numbers, which need to be stored. The number of parameters per device is always the same. However, different devices may require a different number of parameters to be stored. For example, device A always writes exactly 5 parameters, and device B always writes 12 parameters.
Some devices may collect a few thousand parameters per minute.
I can restrict the required queries to the following:

Read/write queries happen once every few minutes
Write query always writes all parameters for a single device at a given moment in time.
Read query always reads all parameters for a single device in a given time interval. The time interval is most usually a few hours to a day, but on rare occasions could reach half a year.

We already use influxdb for storing other kind of measurement data, so I am attempting to understand if this problem can be efficiently solved with influxdb, and if yes how.
My ideas for the schemas are as as follows:

Table has 2 fields: parameter id and parameter value. For example




Time
DeviceID
ParameterID
Value




Now
A
0
0.03


Now
A
1
0.1


...
...
...
....


Now
B
0
1.2


Now
B
1
1.3


...
...
...
....


1 min ago
A
0
0.04


1 min ago
A
1
0.12


...
...
...
....




Table has Nmax fields: all possible parameter values, where Nmax is the upper bound on the total number of parameters that might be needed. Each device that uses N < Nmax parameters will fill in the first N parameters, and not the rest.




Time
DeviceID
P1
P2
...
P1000




Now
A
0.03
0.1
...
1.45


Now
B
1.2
1.3
...
NAN


...
...
...
...
...
...


1 min ago
A
0.04
0.12
...
2.75



Questions

Is influxdb a good tool for my use case?
If yes, what schema should I use: idea 1, idea 2, or something else?
How does the performance of different solutions roughly compares? It is intended to run this solution for several years for a few dozen devices.

What have I looked at already
A similar question has already been considered. However, none of the answers explicitly address performance differences between the approaches. Further, that question explicitly deals with an easier situation - uniform number of parameters measured per timestamp. In my case, the number of parameters measured varies as stated above. So, this question does not address my concerns.

Yes, InfluxDB is well-suited for time-series data with high write and query frequencies, such as IoT device metrics that you're looking to do.
The first table seems to be more efficient as it avoids sparse data issue and will lead to efficient querying. I would modify the schema of "Idea 1" to the following so it's scalable with high parameter (cardinality).
measurement: device_data
tags: device_id
fields: param_1, param_2, ..., param_N
timestamp

In this schema:

Use a single measurement called "device_data"
Use "device_id" as a tag to identify each device
Create a field for each parameter (param_1, param_2, etc.)
Use InfluxDB's built-in timestamp


Thank you for your answer. (1) Could you clarify your modification? You say in the text that you support idea 1, which has only 2 fields, but then proceed to offer a modification that has N fields, akin to the idea 2. So which idea do you actually support? (2) "Seems to be more efficient" is not something I can rely on to make decisions. Do you have any evidence in support that statement?

Best would be if you run a test with your dataset

In an ideal world, yes, but it is quite an expensive test to put terabytes of data into a test database just to see if the schema scales well. That's exactly the job of the database creators.
